# Editing cells in a DataGridView that displays XML files

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to edit cells in a datagridview, I'm programming using Windows forms and C#, so some preface to the issue, I have an .xml file that I am reading in and displaying information on several different tabs, note each of these files are about 100k+ lines. Reading and displaying information is simple enough, but when I go to edit and save them in the same document again I run into a problem. If I make multiple edits to one node and move on, it will only make one edit to that node before moving on. Now I cant give you the exact xml file as it contains proprietary information, but here is an example of the structure of one of nodes I am trying to edit:

```xml
<EUParameters>
    <EUParameter FtirKey="1" Ftir="2" TimeSource="3" Trigger="" Algorithm="" Calibration_ID="4" Effective="5" Verified="1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM" MetStat="5" SignConvention="" Type="6" Op="7" Description="example" Units="numbers" ID="exmaple">
        <Polynomial Set="" Degree="" />
        <Sources />
        <Arguments />
        <Expression></Expression>
        <Syllables>
            <Syllable LSB="" MSB="" Word="" WordInc="" Frame="" FrameInc="" Number="" />
        </Syllables>
    </EUParameter>
```

There's are thousands of nodes like this, and I want to be able to edit every single attribute within the node, here is the way I am handling the editing:

```
    private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveChanges();
    }
    private void SaveChanges()
    {
        // Update the XML file with the modified values
        UpdateXmlFile();

        MessageBox.Show("Changes saved successfully.");

        // Clear the list of edited cells after saving
        editedCells.Clear();
    }

    private void UpdateXmlFile()
    {
        // Load the XML file
        XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(filePath);

        int euParameterIndex = 0; // Counter to keep track of EUParameter index

        foreach (CellEdit cellEdit in editedCells)
        {
            string attribute = cellEdit.Attribute;
            string label = cellEdit.Label;

            // Find the EUParameter node based on its index in the XML structure
            XElement euParameterNode = xmlDocument.Descendants("EUParameter")
                .ElementAtOrDefault(euParameterIndex);

            if (euParameterNode != null)
            {
                // Update the attribute value
                XAttribute attributeElement = euParameterNode.Attribute(attribute);
                if (attributeElement != null)
                {
                    attributeElement.Value = label;
                }
            }

            euParameterIndex++; // Increment the EUParameter index for the next iteration
        }

        // Save the updated XML file
        xmlDocument.Save(filePath);
    }

    private bool IsAttributeValid(string attributeValue)
    {
        string[] validAttributes = { "ID", "Description", "Units", "FtirKey", "Ftir", "TimeSource", "Trigger", "Algorithm", "Calibration_ID", "Effective", "Verified", "MetStat", "SignConvention", "Type", "Op" };
        return validAttributes.Contains(attributeValue);
    }

    private class CellEdit
    {
        public int EUParameterCount { get; }
        public int ColumnIndex { get; }
        public string Attribute { get; }
        public string Label { get; }

        public CellEdit(int euParameterCount, int columnIndex, string attribute, string label)
        {
            EUParameterCount = euParameterCount;
            ColumnIndex = columnIndex;
            Attribute = attribute;
            Label = label;
        }
    }
```

I am wanting to be able to edit multiple attributes within a node and edit multiple attributes within other nodes as well. When i hit save I want those changes to be made accordingly.